# Moving files to new drive - but preserve Symlinks (lots of them) from a backup application

Tags: rsync, backup, symlink

I have used a backup program from the last few years that uses Rysnc to backup my files and maintain versions etc. The system in question is Rsync-time-backup - https://github.com/laurent22/rsync-time-backup

It creates a base backup of XX GB in size and then performs a lot of symlinking for subsequent backups if the files in question have not changed.

As an example for the last 4 years the total size of data file backups is 850GB - whilst the source files are 180GB in size. This is with keeping Yearly backups, 12 monthly backups etc etc

Anyway i now want to move this whole thing to a new Hard drive (replacing an old MDADM array with new drives in a new Array)

I have tried to do an Rysnc of this backup data to the new mounted drive - but it appears to be expanding each of the symlinks into realfiles and hence is chewing up a heap of disk space. Is there a away to tell rsynch to copy the whole structure and maintain the symlinks within that structure rather than expanding them ?

Craig

Comment: If you have GNU `cp`, then use `cp -a`. Else, with the proper options, `rsync` can do the same. If you prefer `rsync`, add the command you used to your question, we will tell you what option is missing.

Comment: if it's hardlinks, `rsync -aH`. alternatively switch to restic, borg, ... other backup solutions that do their own deduplications

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a away to tell `rsync` to copy the whole structure and maintain the symlinks within that structure rather than expanding them

Absolutely. You will also want to maintain any metadata that `rsync` may have put into the extended attributes associated with each file. Run this as root (or with `sudo`):

```
rsync -avXXH /path/to/source/ /path/to/target
```

This is a repeatable command, i.e. if it's stopped part-way through you can run it again and it will pick up from where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

`tar` is pretty good at preserving symlinks. And it works very well over arbitrary links. Try something like

```
tar c . | ssh <target> tar x
```

If it's mounted locally, you can do

```
(cd <source> ; tar c . ) | (cd <destination> ; tar x)
```